# Redis. Как получить сразу 10 ключей и их данные

Tags: redis

Я сделал систему counter хранилища для моих постов с помощью redis.
Для этого спользую https://redis.io/commands/hincrby/

Он в себе хранит ключи как: likes, comments.

Я хочу вывести на страницу сразу 10 постов и их counter информацию.

Я не хочу бежать через foreach и каждый раз делать запрос в redis для получения count информации из каждого ключа.

Могу ли я одним запросом в redis получить сразу 10 ключей и их инфу?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте команду [HMGET](https://redis.io/commands/hmget/):

```
HMGET key field1 field2 ...
```